# How do I pass parameter of type enum to a method in Apex?

Tags: enums, apex

[image]

```html
public class EnumTest {
    
    Public  enum Season {Spring,Summer,fall,winter}
    
    Public static Void SeasonFinder(Season  CurrentSeason)
    {
        
        
        
        If(CurrentSeason == Season.Spring || CurrentSeason == Season.fall )
        {
            System.debug('Neither cold nor hot');
        
        } else if(CurrentSeason == Season.Summer)
        {
            System.debug('It is hot');
            
        } Else if(CurrentSeason == Season.Winter)
        {
             System.debug('It is Cold');
        }
    Else 
    {
        System.debug('Invalid Season');
    }

}
}
```

I need to call the function SeasonFinder. But how do I pass the parameter of type season? Am getting error like variable season does not exist.

Comment: enumTest obj = new enumTest();
obj.SeasonFinder(obj.Season.Summer); gives me error message season doesnot exist

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it as static so the call would be like this:

```
seasonTest.SeasonFinder(EnumTest.Season.Summer)
```